# How to check for conditions on click of calender event using fullcalender?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have been using fullcalender in codeigniter for displaying events on calender. On clicking those events its redirecting to the url passed.

But I want to check some conditions and change url as per that, How can it be done?

Here's my code in view

```
<script>
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     eventSources: [
         {
             events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                 $.ajax({
                 url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/faculty_role/Dashboard/get_events',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 data: {

                 },
                 success: function(msg) {
                     var events = msg.events;

                     callback(events);
                 }
                 });
             }
         },
     ]

});
</script>
```

Code in Controller

```
 public function get_events()
 {
     // Our Start and End Dates
     $this->load->library('session');
     $this->load->model("faculty_role/dashboard_model");
     $emp_id=$this->session->userdata['empid'];
     $events = $this->dashboard_model->get_events($emp_id);
     $data_events = array();
        foreach($events->result() as $r) {
       $url='';
       $color='';
       if($r->stats==0){
         $url= base_url().'index.php/faculty_role/Dashboard/view_student/'.$r->schedule_id.'/'.$r->end_time.'/'.$r->date;
         $color='Blue';
       }
       elseif($r->stats==1){
           $url='#';
           $color='Green';
       }
       elseif($r->stats==2){
            $url='#';
           $color='Red';
       }
        $data_events[] = array(
            "title" => $r->schedule_id.'|'.$r->module_name,
            "start" => $r->date.' '.$r->start_time,
            "end" => $r->date.' '.$r->end_time,
            "description"=>$r->fellowship_name.' '.$r->cohort_name,
            "url"=>$url,
            "backgroundColor"=>$color
                );
        }
        echo json_encode(array("events" => $data_events));
        exit();
 }
```

Comment: waht you want exactely ? also in backend or just front ?

Comment: On the event click i want to compare date and if the event date is greater then current date, I want to stop user on same page else redirect to different page

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the "eventClick" callback, which, as suggested by its name, runs whenever an event on the calendar is clicked. You write code there to decide what to do. Within this function you have the option to cancel the navigation to the event's URL and do something else instead. This is done by returning `false` from the callback function.

For example:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
  //check whether the clicked event's start date (normalised to the start of the day for matching purposes) is later than today's date
  if (calEvent.start.startOf("day").isAfter(moment())) {
    return false; //this will prevent navigation to the event's URL
  }
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/99/ for a working demo.

This is all clearly documented on the fullCalendar website: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/